# GitPython equivalent of "git remote show origin"?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm trying to update a Python script that checks the status of a handful of local repositories against remotes from using **subprocess** to using **GitPython**. What is the equivalent command in **GitPython** for `git remote show origin`, or what is the better way to check that the local repo is *fast-forwardable* or *out-of-date* (etc.)?

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: <url>
  Push  URL: <url>
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    XYZ    tracked
    master tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    XYZ    merges with remote XYZ
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    XYZ    pushes to XYZ    (up to date)
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

The last two lines are my primary concern. It looks like this might be possible with **GitPython** by iterating over `git.Repo.heads` and `git.Repo.remotes.origin.refs` and comparing `.master.commit` (etc.) hashes. This seems a good deal more work than the above single native git command and will require even more work to tell which side(s) is/are outdated. I was expecting something like `git.Repo.remotes.origin.status()`. What is the proper way to determine this in **GitPython**?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `git.cmd.Git()` if gitpython doesn't wrap wanted functionality. It directly calls git so it's quite convenient, although I guess that mostly it's just a subprocess' wrapper:

```
import git

g = git.cmd.Git("/path/to/git/repo")
print(g.execute("git remote show origin"))  # git remote show origin
print(g.execute(["git", "remote", "show", "origin"]))  # same as above
print(g.remote(verbose=True))  # git remote --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything better than running `git remote show origin` as a subprocess if you need a concise report of every branch.   If your interest is in a single branch, assuming you've done a fetch, you can check how many commits you are behind
or ahead like this:

```
commits_behind = list(repo.iter_commits(
            '{branch}..{tracking_branch}'.format(
                branch=branch,
                tracking_branch=repo.heads[branch].tracking_branch())))

commits_ahead = list(repo.iter_commits(
            '{tracking_branch}..{branch}'.format(
                branch=branch,
                tracking_branch=repo.heads[branch].tracking_branch())))
```